# Zenbu errors in log file: Undefined variable: rule_cond

Tags: ee2, error, solspace-calendar, zenbu

I'm trying to identify and fix the errors that I keep seeing in my log files. I'm on EE2.6.1, with Zenbu 1.8.3, and I'm seeing the following errors all over my log files.

`ERROR - 2013-08-26 13:17:31 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: rule_cond /home/highland/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/zenbu/views/zenbu_index.php 28
ERROR - 2013-08-26 13:17:31 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: rule_cond /home/highland/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/zenbu/views/zenbu_index.php 22`

I'm not sure if this is related or not, but I recently also had an issue with Zenbu when trying to display the "Dates & Options" field from Solspace Calendar events.

Any insights into the cause of this, or possible fix? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest version, 1.8.5.1 (as of this writing)? Also, Zenbu support is usually available on http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zenbu/viewforum/1455 or on the zenbustudio.com site.

Comment: Thanks, Zenbuman. I'll try to upgrade and see if the issues goes away.

Comment: I have upgraded my Zenbu to the latest version, and the problem persists. I even tried totally uninstalling Zenbu and re-installing it, in case some settings were causing the issue. But the problem still persists. Looking at the file /views/zenbu_index.php on lines 22 and 28... it's looking at a variable called $rule_cond. But where is that variable instantiated? It looks to be instantiated in the foreach on line 97

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed for next release (i.e. after version 1.8.5.2).

In the meantime, if you want to try and fix this right away, go in **/system/expressionengine/third_party/zenbu/views/zenbu_index.php** and change line 22 from

```
<?php $selected = $optval == $rule_cond['field'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>
```

to

```
<?php $selected = isset($rule_cond['field']) && $optval == $rule_cond['field'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>
```

and line 28 from

```
<?php $selected = $val == $rule_cond['field'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>
```

to

```
<?php $selected = isset($rule_cond['field']) && $val == $rule_cond['field'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>
```